# Как сделать галерею галерей Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, slider, плагин

Встала задача:
Передо мной есть блок с картинками.
По нажатию на любую из этих картинок, должна открываться галерея, которая содержит в себе первоначальную картинку, а так же и другие связанные с ней картинки, которые я должен мочь сам добавить.

Таким образом стоит вопрос, что технически нужно создать галерею галерей, где повторюсь, как вы поняли, элементами галереи выступают не просто изображения, а получается изображения с ссылкой на галерею.

Не могли бы подсказать с помощью каких плагинов или вариантов можно было бы реализовать данную идею?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Берёте и покупаете (или скачиваете бесплатный) ваааще любой плагин галереи на WP. Только трастовый, с большим количеством загрузок, желательно и отзывы почитать и что бы версию вашего WP поддерживал (И смотрите на историю обновлений, это даст понимание того, на сколько вендор ответственно поддерживает свой плагин). Например, сейчас работаю с [этим](http://plugins.roninwp.com/maika/).
- Создаёте галереи в необходимом количестве. Как, думаю, не надо объяснять.
- Создаёте страницу с сеткой изображений. Каждое изображение оборачивает ссылкой на пост/страницу, в контент которой, в свою очередь, вставляете шорткод/ссылку на конкретную галерею.